# Getting properties in logback.groovy from application.yml

Tags: grails, logback

I'm developing an application using `Grails 3.3.10` ,I'm using `logback` to log to the DB and it's working fine , what I need to get the DB properties in `logback.groovy` from the `application.yml` rather putting them statically , I tried different ways but not working for example for getting the driverClass , I tried `driverClass="${Holders.config.getProperty('environments.development.dataSource.driverClassName')}"` but getting `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'environments.development.dataSource.driverClassName' on null object`

Any recommendations ?

Comment: Please add the things you have tried and how it failed

Comment: @cfrick edited the original post

Comment: any ideas to solve this ?